# Excel VBA copy and paste from multiple sheets, excluding certain sheets, depending on the value in a certain cell

Tags: excel, vba, loops, copy-paste

Please go easy on me, I am new to this.
I have a number of work sheets, and I have information populating into those sheets from other worksheets in the spreadsheet.
I would like to summarise the sheets that have populated into one sheet for printing.
The idea is to find any sheet with values past cell B10 (values not formulas) and copy the entire contents of the sheet, onto the last blank cell - offset by 1 (leaving a blank line in between) in the "Output" sheet.
So far I am using "AHU Sheet 1", AHU Sheet 2" (both have populated values in B11 and below) and "AHU Sheet 3" which only has a formula in B11, this is a test sheet for empty information.

I want to exclude other sheets.

my code so far, which does nothing at all.

Please help :)

```
Sub printAll()

Dim ws As Worksheet
        For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Task Lists" And ws.Name <> "AHU-FCU Asset List" And ws.Name <> "Direct Expansion Asset List" And ws.Name <> "Refrigeration Asset List" And ws.Name <> "General Fans Asset List" And ws.Name <> "Lookups" And ws.Range("B10").Value <> "" Then

            ws.Cells.Copy

        Sheets("Output").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset (1)
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        End If
    Next ws
 

End Sub
```

Edit after @IgorPokalev Help

```
 Sub printAll()

    Dim ws, wso As Worksheet, lastRow_ws, lastRow_wso As Long
    Set wso = Sheets("Output")
    
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Task Lists" And _
            ws.Name <> "AHU-FCU Asset List" And _
            ws.Name <> "Direct Expansion Asset List" And _
            ws.Name <> "Refrigeration Asset List" And _
            ws.Name <> "General Fans Asset List" And _
            ws.Name <> "Lookups" And _
            ws.Name <> "Output" And _
            ws.Range("B11").Value <> "" Then
            
            lastRow_ws = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row 'get last row of data based on column B in each ws
            lastRow_wso = wso.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row 'get last row of data copied into the Output sheet based on column B
            ws.Rows("1:" & lastRow_ws).Copy _
                Destination:=wso.Range("A" & lastRow_wso + IIf(lastRow_wso > 1, 2, 0)) 'IIf(lastRow_wso > 1, 2, 0) adds a blank separator row
        End If
    Next
 
End Sub
```

This is A through H on one of the sheets, kind of messy when you see it here. If there are tasks from B10 down, I would like to copy it to "Output", formatted the same way it is input. The tasks are imported via a formula. I hope this is helpful.
Rows 1 through 5 are the header information with the equipment details.
A=Empty
B=  Tasks:
Inspect and clean outdoor air intakes and exhaust air discharges where necessary.
etc.
[Formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsH3n.png)
[Full sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3PJD.png)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17E3A.png)

Comment: I see the 'Formatting' screenprint you attached. I'm assuming the 'Tasks:' in bold is in range B10? 1) Would you like to copy just the Tasks: B10 to last row or do you want to copy the Assets table as well? 2) If B11 contains a formula, would you still like to copy the Tasks but just the values not the formulas or skip that sheet entirely?

Comment: Im struggling with this format, bare with me

Comment: Thank you, I have added a screenshot of the full sheet that I am copying from, the tasks will change depending on what type of service it is, and that comes from one of the sheets that we discluded from the loop. Ive also added "Output" to the discluded sheets

Comment: What does the output look like? It is unclear what exactly the criteria are for a sheet to be copied, in particular, the 'B10-B11-formula' part.

Comment: OK, so it looks like it is working, but it is bring over the formulas, not the values. I would like the values to come over (paste as values) but I still need the heading formatted. I slightly altered the code.

Comment: Share a screenshot of the desired output. If you're talking about Igor's answer then comment in his comment section (below his answer).

Comment: I have put a picture "Output" at the bottom of my main question, I am not yet approved to add pictures  otherwise. I will comment below on Igors Post.

Comment: 1) It seems you are populating the 'Tasks:' via formulas that are pulling from the multiple excluded sheets in your code (Task Lists, AHU-FCU Asset List...) - since these tasks are formula derived, would you still like to copy them or skip such a sheet and only copy sheets with hard coded/non formula tasks? 2) 'Tasks:' begins on "B6" in the 'Full sheet' screenprint you added - would you like to copy from "B6" down to last row in column B or would you also like to include the header information (rows 1 through 5)?

Comment: Hi Igor, yes thats right, I am populating the tasks from formulas, using multiple excluded sheets. I would like to copy everything from B3 to the end of the tasks, as the header will have the equipment details in it for each tasklist that was completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works for you:

```
Sub printAll()

    Dim ws, wso As Worksheet, lastRow_ws, lastRow_wso As Long
    Set wso = Sheets("Output")
    
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Task Lists" And _
            ws.Name <> "AHU-FCU Asset List" And _
            ws.Name <> "Direct Expansion Asset List" And _
            ws.Name <> "Refrigeration Asset List" And _
            ws.Name <> "General Fans Asset List" And _
            ws.Name <> "Lookups" And _
            ws.Range("B11").value <> "" And _
            Not (ws.Range("B11").HasFormula) Then 'check if "B11" is a formula
            
            lastRow_ws = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row 'get last row of data based on column B in each ws
            lastRow_wso = wso.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row 'get last row of data copied into the Output sheet based on column B
            ws.Rows("1:" & lastRow_ws).Copy _
                Destination:=wso.Range("A" & lastRow_wso + IIf(lastRow_wso > 1, 2, 0)) 'IIf(lastRow_wso > 1, 2, 0) adds a blank separator row
        End If
    Next
 
End Sub
```

This code copies rows 1 to last row based on column B data from each of the worksheets that meet your criteria. I'm not sure what your data looks like and if column B would have the true last row though.

[image: Output]

[Edit]

See if this works:

```
Sub printAll()
    Dim ws, wso As Worksheet, lastRow_ws, lastRow_wso As Long
    Set wso = Sheets("Output")
    
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Task Lists" And _
            ws.Name <> "AHU-FCU Asset List" And _
            ws.Name <> "Direct Expansion Asset List" And _
            ws.Name <> "Refrigeration Asset List" And _
            ws.Name <> "General Fans Asset List" And _
            ws.Name <> "Lookups" And _
            ws.Range("B11").value <> "" Then 'the 'Tasks:' list begins on B7 in your screenprint, change the range from B11 to B7 here if you'd like.
            
            lastRow_ws = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row 'get last row of data based on column B in each ws
            lastRow_wso = wso.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row 'get last row of data copied into the Output sheet based on column B
            ws.Rows("1:" & lastRow_ws).Copy
            wso.Range("A" & lastRow_wso + IIf(lastRow_wso > 1, 2, 0)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme
            wso.Range("A" & lastRow_wso + IIf(lastRow_wso > 1, 2, 0)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
'            wso.Range("A" & lastRow_wso + IIf(lastRow_wso > 1, 2, 0)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

The tasks list seems to start on B7. I added a comment in the code where you can change the last If condition to look at B7 instead of B11, depending on your needs.

Comment: Thank you so much for jumping on this sofast :) 
Still not working :(
It is only copying over the heading, thats a good start, better than ive done so far :)

Comment: Edit after our help Igor. It does copy over, but only the formulas and the header nicely formatted, not the values from the previous sheet, Please see the image "Output" in my main question. I have slightly altered your code which is also in the main question.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info and clarifications. I've edited the post to add revised code which should copy just the values and formats.

Comment: Thank you Igor, I did remove some rows from the top, this moved the tasks to begin at B7. I forgot to mention, good pickup :) 
This does not work, now it will only copy over AHU sheet 1 and not sheet 2, I have tried with B7 also.  I may have found a workaround by using absolute formulas in the sheets I want to copy and letting the formula spill, so I dont have to hard code all of the formulas for each task. This seems to be working with your original code. 
I cant tell you how much I appreciate what you have done for me Igor, I have been trying to crack this all holidays. Thank you!

Comment: My pleasure, I'm open to continue working on this with you until you have a fully working solution. "now it will only copy over AHU sheet 1 and not sheet 2" - what is different between AHU sheet 1 and AHU sheet 2?

Comment: Thank you Igor. The difference between the two sheets, AHU sheet 2 is a quarterly maintenance and it only has tasks from B7 to B19, instead of all the way to 35. I also had not run the formula down in each cell, it had spilled eg: =IF('AHU sheet 2'!$B$3<>"", IFS('AHU-FCU Asset List'!$I$4="Monthly", 'Task Lists'!$B$2:$B$30,'AHU-FCU Asset List'!$I$4="Quarterly", 'Task Lists'!$C$2:$C$14 ), "") returning Task lists C2:C14 for Quarterly in a single cell spills down. Where in AHU Sheet 1, I have filled each cell with an IFS formula for Monthly or Quarterly.

Comment: Perhaps B11 in AHU sheet 2 is empty then since you're saying you haven't run the formulas in each cell. Perhaps we could edit this line of code: ws.Range("B11").value <> "" Then into this: ws.Range("B6").value = "Tasks:" Then. That way even if some task cells are empty we'll still validate the sheet as eligible to be copied. Alternatively, if you're only copying sheets named AHU sheet #, we could validate which sheets to copy based on their names, e.g.: AHU sheet 1, 2, 3....

Comment: All the templates by default have "Tasks" in B6, so it will still pick up empty checklists. Unfortunately, there will be 100 AHU sheets, 100 direct expansion checklists, 100 refrigeration checklists etc. we wont use all of those each month, only the ones listed on a summary page, thats where the data comes from to tell the sheets what cycle was performed and what checklist to import, and also what information to use in the header. This is quite complex. If I could load the sheet somehwere for you, I would happily, as it is all test data so far.

Comment: Lets try to formulate a set of conditions to encompass the myriad of differences between the 100's of sheets to firmly select only the ones you need. Say all AHU sheets have the value 'Tasks:" in B6, do they have any tasks listed in "B7" and below - if not we can skip these sheets. You mentioned B11 as a criteria in your post - are you looking for AHU sheets with a certain number of tasks populated? There is certainly a solution, we just have to figure it out.

Comment: You could share the workbook via google drive, but do consider that this is an open forum and many people would be able to view it - if you do decide to do that I recommend you remove any sensitive information beforehand and simply share a template.